# How to create stored procedure in SQL Server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I'm new to stored procedures world and in one of my projects I'm trying to implement stored procedure for the search process. I'm not sure if everything I created is correct. Also I'm wondering if this code has any leaks or vulnerability for SQL injection. Here is example of my stored procedure:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Search_Dictionary]
    @FilterBy INT = NULL,
    @Name VARCHAR(50) = NULL,
    @Code CHAR(2) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT RecID, Status, Code, Name
    FROM Dictionary
    WHERE 
        (@FilterBy = 1 AND Name LIKE '%'+@Name+'%')
        OR (@FilterBy = 2 AND Code = @Code)
        OR (@FilterBy = 3 AND @Name IS NULL AND @Code IS NULL);
END
```

Here is example on how I call this procedure:

```
EXEC Search_Dictionary @FilterBy = 1, @Name = "Grant", @Code = NULL;
```

I just want to prevent if for example filter by is 2 that should search query by `Code` column returns any result if user pass word `Grant`. In that case should return 0 records. Also if anyone have any suggestions on how to improve the code please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: This looks like a potentially better fit for Code Review than for Stack Overflow.  We can help with identifiable problems, but if you're just looking for general critiques of your code that's better done elsewhere.

Comment: What is a good place for code review? Any websites?

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Correct? Only you can ascertain that - does it return the correct result or not? I will say that it's a "kitchen sink" stored procedure which can suffer from parameter sniffing

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Can you explain more about parameter sniffing issue?

Comment: I could but you would learn a lot more if you just googled "kitchen sink parameter sniffing". In short, your SP is run it is optimised for whatever parameter is used the _first time_ it is run. When you run it for a different parameter it tries to use the same optmisation pattern (query plan), but for "kitchen sink" procedures, this might be a completely different set of data which actually has bad performance.